# Maximum Likelihood Estimation for State Space Models using BFGS

Tags: optimization

I have written some code that can do Kalman filtering (using a number of different Kalman-type filters [Information Filter et al.]) for Linear Gaussian State Space Analysis for an n-dimensional state vector.

Let us consider the linear Gaussian State Space model

$$y_t = \mathbf{Z}_{t}\alpha_{t} + \epsilon_{t},$$
$$\alpha_{t + 1} = \mathbf{T}_{t}\alpha_{t} + \mathbf{R}_{t}\eta_{t},$$

where $y_{t}$ is our observation vector, $\alpha_{t}$ our state vector at time step $t$. The quantities in bold are the transformation matrices of the state space model which are set according to the characteristics of the system under consideration. We also have

$$\epsilon_{t} \sim NID(0, \mathbf{H}_{t}),$$
$$\eta_{t} \sim NID(0, \mathbf{Q}_{t}),$$
$$\alpha_{1} \sim NID(a_{1}, \mathbf{P}_{1}).$$

where $t = 1,\ldots, n$. Now, I have derived and implemented the recursion for the Kalman Filter for this generic state space model by guessing the initial parameters and variance matrices $\mathbf{H}_{1}$ and $\mathbf{Q}_{1}$.

where the points are the Nile River water levels for Jan over 100 years, the line is the Kalamn Estimated state, and the dashed lines are the 90% confidence levels.

Now, in order to estimate the initial parameters of my model ($\mathbf{H}_{1}$ and $\mathbf{Q}_{1}$) I have adopted the Expectation Maximisation method to maximise the loglikelihood function

$$\log L(Y_{n}|\psi) = -\frac{np}{2}\log(2\pi) - \frac{1}{2}\sum^{n}_{t = 1}(log|\mathbf{F}_{t}| + v^{\mathsf{T}}_{t}\mathbf{F}_{t}^{-1}v_{t}), \;\;\;\; (1)$$

with respect to parameter vector $\psi$. Where $v_{t}$ is the state error and $\mathbf{F}_{t}$ is the state error variance. The vector $\psi$ contains the unknown parameters (i.e., either the measurement and state disturbance variances themselves, or a re-parametrisation of these same variances, see below)

A crucial role in the maximisation of (1) is played by the gradient or score vector

$$\partial_{1}(\psi) = \partial \log L(Y_{n}|\psi)/\partial\psi,\;\;\;\; (2)$$

At least two algorithms can be used to maximise (1). The first is the so-called EM (Expectation-Maximisation) algorithm, and the second is the BFGS (Broyden-Fletcher-Goldfarb-Shannon) algorithm. I have successfully implemented the EM algorithm and this is providing correct results but is very slow; in light of this I now wish to implement the BFGS algorithm as this has better performance.

So, from (2) using Taylor's theorem we can write

$$\partial_{1}(\psi) \simeq \tilde{\partial}_{1}(\psi) + \tilde{\partial}_{2}(\psi)(\psi - \tilde{\psi}),$$

where $\partial_{2}(\psi)$ is the Hessian matrix or second derivative of the loglikelihood function wrt $\psi$ and $\tilde{\partial}_{N}(\psi) = \partial_{N}(\psi)|_{\psi = \tilde{\psi}}$. So now we can write our updated parameter vector as

$$\bar{\psi} = \tilde{\psi} - \tilde{\partial}_{2}(\psi)^{-1}\tilde{\partial}_{1}(\psi) = \tilde{\psi} - s\tilde{\pi(\psi)}.\;\;\;\; (3)$$

where here $\tilde{\pi(\psi)} = - \tilde{\partial}_{2}(\psi)^{-1}\tilde{\partial}_{1}(\psi)$ and $s$ is our step size. So the basic outline of the BFGS algorithm to get our parameter vector and maximize (1) using BFGS is:

1. Initialise parameter vector $\psi = \psi^{*}$.
2. Then apply the Kalman and disturbance smoothing filters and thus for score vector (2) at $\psi = \psi^{*}$. When running the Kalman Filter evaluate the log-likelihood function.
3. Use (3) to obtain new values for $\psi$ given by $\psi^{+}$ and go back to step 2 until the value of loglikelihood function (1) no longer improves.

This seems fine, but my problem is how to calculate the step size $s$ in (3) above. I know a line search is required, but remember $\psi$ is a vector and it is not clear what function I can use in a traditional line search technique in order to evaluate $s$.

**Question: what line search method should I use in order to evaluate $s$?**

---

Ps. Assume that I would like to use the zoom line search algorithm (algorithm 3.5 of [Numerical Optimization by Nocedal & Wright](http://faculty.bracu.ac.bd/~faruqe/books/numericalanalysis/Numerical%20Optimization%202ed.pdf)).

---

Further to the very helpful answer by @LKlevin, I want to classify my problems more explicitly...

$^{*}$Most (L-)BFGS methods accept vector functions, that is a function $f$ that depends on a n-dimensional (in this case let us assume two-dimensions) parameter vector $\mathbf{x} = (x_{1}, x_{2})^{\mathsf{T}}$, so if we had $F(x_{1}, x_{2}) = 2x_{2}^{2} + 4x_{2}$ you would pass into the BFGS algo. $F$ and $\nabla{F}$. This is fine and the text I reference as a PDF above tells me all I need to know here in terms of using BFGS to minimise this function.

However, in the case I have above, from (3) we have

$$\bar{\psi} = \tilde{\psi} - \tilde{\partial}_{2}(\psi)^{-1}\tilde{\partial}_{1}(\psi) = \tilde{\psi} - s\tilde{\pi(\psi)},$$

which can be written as

$$\left[\begin{array}{c}
\psi_{1}\\
\psi_{2}\\
\end{array}\right]  = \left[\begin{array}{c}
\tilde{\psi}_{1}\\
\tilde{\psi}_{2}\\
\end{array}\right] - \mathcal{H}\,\partial_{1}(\psi)\left[\begin{array}{c}
\tilde{\psi}_{1}\\
\tilde{\psi}_{2}\\
\end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}{c}
\tilde{\psi}_{1}\\
\tilde{\psi}_{2}\\
\end{array}\right] - s\left[\begin{array}{c}
\tilde{\pi}_{1}(\psi_{1})\\
\tilde{\pi}_{2}(\psi_{2})\\
\end{array}\right],$$

where $\mathcal{H}$ is the inverse Hessian matrix.

So the problem seems to consist of $n$ linear optimizations, not a single equation depending on a vector of parameters. My problem here is the use of the vectors $\psi$ in this case above.

So, can I optimise this without splitting the n-dimensional (2 dimensional in the example above) vector into $n$ equations which I can optimise using functions as described in the paragraph $^{*}$ above?

Another issue is that the loglikelihood function is not explicitly dependent on $\psi$, so how can i use this in the line search method?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so Kalman filters are not my forte, but non-linear optimization is, so let's give it a go.

You want to obtain $\psi$, not by solving your equation (3), but by maximizing (1), so

$\psi^+ = arg\max_\psi (\log L(Y_n | \psi))$.

Your stepsize $s$ is in theory found by

$s^+ = arg\max_s (\log L(Y_n | \psi+s\pi))$, however in practice you don't need to find the exact minimum, it simply needs to fulfil the Wolfe conditions, as described in Nocedal & Wright.

BFGS algorithms have the advantage that the step size is typically around 1, and the simple [Armijo linesearch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking_line_search) works quite well. You will probably get faster convergence with the zoom linesearch.

[This article](http://cas.umt.edu/math/reports/bardsley/bfgs_vkf.pdf) has a nice description of a Kalman filter using the LBFGS algorithm.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply. My problem is not with the method so much. It is more that I the function (1) is not an explicit function of the vector $\psi$ AND $\psi$ is a _vector_. All BFGS methods i have implemented before have accepted 'vector's but these were parameter vectors, that is a function $F(x_{1}, x_{2}) = 2 x_{1}^{2} + 5x_{2}$, here we _actually_ have a vector in the true sense; (3) is a vector equation, of single variables... I will try and classify the problem further in an extension to the question; give me a minute.

Comment: That $\psi$ is a vector should not matter; as you note in your question, BFGS is a nonlinear programming algorithm that can be applied to scalar objective functions with vector-valued inputs. If you can calculate (1) at all from $\psi$ as an input, and you can calculate reasonable gradient information (needed to approximate the Hessian matrix), you should have all the information you need to use the LBFGS algorithm.

Comment: I take the point that I am minimizing the loglikelihood function and this is the same as what I have outlined in the _comment_ above. However, the likelihood function (1) is not explicitly dependent on $\psi$. In my case $\psi_{1}$ to $\psi_{n}$ are the diagonal components of my variance matrix $\mathbf{H}$ and $\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{H})$. So in order to satisfy the Wolfe conditions I will have to check whether the loglikelihood increases from the previous iteration of the algorithm; but what do I use to update $log(L)$? Can I construct and new $\mathbf{H}$ from $\psi_{1-n}$ and use that?

Comment: You would construct a new $\bf H$ from $\psi_{n-1}+s \pi$ and use that to evaluate (1). Consider if you can reformulate the problem to calculate $\log L_n(s)$ fast. For the BFGS algorithm to be truely efficient, evaluating (1) should be much faster than calculating the gradient (2), as is typically the case.